# Почему "увидеть" склоняется по 2-ому спряжению?

Tags: глаголы, морфология

Почему глагол *увидеть* склоняется по 2-ому спряжению? *видеть* относится ко 2-ому спряжению, а *увидеть* -- это другой глагол и должен относиться к 1-ому спряжению.

Comment: Если бесприставочный глагол относится к какому-то спряжению, то и все остальные глаголы, образованные от него при помощи приставок, относятся к тому же самому спряжению. И глаголы не склоняются, а спрягаются, это именные части речи склоняются.

Comment: и уже совсем-совсем педантизм: не "2-ому", а "2-му" :)

Comment: @YellowSky Не совсем так. Сравните *стелить* и *постелить*. *стелить*: 1-ое спр., *ты стел**ешь***; *постелить*, 2 спр., *ты постел**ишь***.

Comment: Как бы там ни было, но [словарь Ушакова даёт формы глагола _стелить_](http://ushakovdictionary.ru/word.php?wordid=74270) так: _стелю_, _стелишь_. Это не опечатка на том сайте, у меня этот словарь есть в бумажном виде, могу отсканировать, если хотите. ABBYY Lingvo x5 даёт параллельные формы _стелишь_ / _стелешь_.

Comment: @graduate: until very recently, *стелить* and its derivatives were regarded colloquialisms, the neutral word being *стлать*. Rosenthal's guides limit usage of *стелить* to infinitive and past forms, replacing its present and future forms with those of *стлать* (as they are phonetically indistinguishable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему должен? Есть глагол *увидать*, вот он действительно другой. А приставка и, соответственно, категория вида на спряжение никак не влияют.

Comment: Глаголы *стелить* и *постелить* имеют разное спряжение.

Comment: @Graduate, *стелить* — это на самом деле *стлать*, у которого вышел из обихода инфинитив и заменился на другой по аналогии.

Comment: @Graduate, я поторопился: точнее будет сказать, что настоящее время у *стелить* полностью контаминировалось со *стлать*. *Видать* на *видеть* никак не повлияло. Каким-то другим вариантам взяться просто неоткуда.